# SpringBoot FeignClient Method has too many paramters with Pageable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-feign

When I try to use Paging with FeignClient I get an error.

**Error:**

```
Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.UserClient.getUserList(com.UserSearchDto,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
```

**Method**

```
@PostMapping("/user/getUserList")
ResponseEntity<Page<UserDto>> getUserList(@RequestBody UserSearchDto searchInputDto, Pageable page);
```

**FeignClientConfig**

```
@Component
public class FeignClientConfigInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Bean
    public Encoder multipartFormEncoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(() -> new HttpMessageConverters(new RestTemplate().getMessageConverters())));
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return new RetreiveMessageErrorDecoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public Client feignClient() {
        return new ApacheHttpClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public Module pageJacksonModule() {
        return new PageJacksonModule();
    }

    @Bean
    public Module sortJacksonModule() {
        return new SortJacksonModule();
    }
}
```

I couldn't find where the problem is.
How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding @SpringQueryMap to method fixed the error.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.SpringQueryMap;

@PostMapping("/user/getUserList")
ResponseEntity<Page<UserDto>> getUserList(@RequestBody UserSearchDto searchInputDto, @SpringQueryMap Pageable page);
```

Comment: this annotation adds query param as body, if this serves your purpose then good, otherwise its best practice to add pageable as part of same object call rather than separate query param

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you give an example for what you said last?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your using @requestbody with pageable as seperate parameters which is not allowed, since request body only supports single object parameters, hence i would suggest to wrap your dto and pageable in a single object and use that object as the request body param.

ex.

```
@PostMapping("/user/getUserList")
ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse<Page<UserDto>>> getUserList(@RequestBody CombinationDto dto);
```

Here CombinationDto can have UserSearchDto and Pageable as separate fields.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I found solution for this problem. I put it as a comment.

Adding @SpringQueryMap to method fixed the error.